# Styling react-native Navigation Drawer Items

Tags: android, ios, react-native, styles

How To styling react-native navigation drawer item's Text.I go through the Documentation but i didnt able to find correct way to do that

[Navigation Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer#Providing-a-custom-contentComponent)

This is My AppContainer

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { ActionCreators } from '../actions';
import Home_ from './Home';
import About from './About';
//Add navigation
import { DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation'

const cunstomeDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
    <View style={{flex: 1, color: 'red',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontFamily: 'cochin',
        letterSpacing: 4}} >
        <DrawerItems {...this.props} />
    </View>
);

const drawerLayout = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Home_ },
    About: { screen: About },

});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1, color: 'red',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontFamily: 'cochin',
        letterSpacing: 4
    }


});

export default connect((state) => { return {} }, mapDispatchToProps)(drawerLayout);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to add some props to DrawerItems component. like below.

```
<DrawerItems {...this.props}  activeTintColor='#2196f3' activeBackgroundColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, .04)' inactiveTintColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, .87)' inactiveBackgroundColor='transparent' style={{backgroundColor: '#000000'}} labelStyle={{color: '#ffffff'}}/>
```

I have customised it with sample values. Update your code and apply whatever font color and background color you want.

Answer (score 1):

Please Tak a look at this [document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/1.x/drawer-navigator.html). check the **contentOptions** properties.